# Does restarting laptop interfere with battery re-calibration?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop

When doing a laptop battery re-calibration is it OK to restart the computer while battery is still recharging or would this interrupt the process?

[I got a new battery yesterday and discharged it overnight - now I have a restart pending due to a new software install and several hours until charge reaches 100%... System in question is a Lenovo T420 running Windows 7 (64 bit)]